# Start process it doesn't work with arguments [vgmstream.exe]

Tags: c#, winforms

I want create a Sound player for  .wav. The files .wav is converted from .bsctm with a .exe called vgmstream. The conversion is success but it doesn't work if I call the proccess in winforms.

Here the code:

```
    private void btn_player_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            if (!status_player)
            {
                btn_player.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.btn_pause;
                if (!File.Exists(((Theme)lbx.SelectedItem).Bgm))
                // No exist
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Bgm not found");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                        player.SoundLocation = ConvertWAW(); 
                    player.Play();
            }
            else
            {
                btn_player.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.btn_player;
                player.Stop();
            }

        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException error)
        {
            //Always show this error.
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
        finally {
            status_player = !status_player;
        }

   private String ConvertWAW()
{
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "vgmstream.exe";
if (File.Exists(((Theme)lbx.SelectedItem).Bgm))
{
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-o " + @"temp.wav" + @" " + ((Theme)lbx.SelectedItem).Bgm;
    // BGM => @"Thems\" + folder_name + @"\bgm.bcstm"
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
   return "temp.wav";
}
return "";
}
```

[When I use the .exe from winforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfS5Z.png)

[Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiVDh.png)

Comment: Try using a full path for the FileName.

Comment: Many thanks again! Now, I already know how use the FileName with relative path too.